# Apache - Run site under sub directory (?)

Tags: apache, ubuntu-18.04

I'm sure it's been answered, but I'm failing to find the right search terms to find the solution.

I have a site (mysite.com) running in Apache, this is working great:

```
<VirtualHost mysite.com:80>
    ServerName www.mysite.com
    ServerAlias *.mysite.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mysite
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to run this site one level up in the url, something like this: `mysite.com/past/2019`

I can't get this to work by modifying the `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` values.

Comment: Can you please explain you want to run same site on one level up or another website?

Comment: Another website.

So, I have a client who runs an annual event.  They want to run the prior year's sites under the same domain.

Answer (score 1):

For this firstly you have to enable the apache2 rewrite module. You can enable this by running the command 'sudo a2enmod rewrite' after this add below line to your apache2 vhost

`<Directory /var/www/mysite>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
</Directory>`

Then restart your apache2 server by running command `sudo service apache2 restart`
Hope it works for you.